# Scripts still loading for uninstalled plugins?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, caching, plugins

I'm using YSlow to troubleshoot a slow-loading Wordpress site, and it's showing that several .js files associated with plugins that I have uninstalled/deleted (in some cases uninstalled several days ago) are still loading -- or trying to load. The plugin files are no longer on the server. If I try to click through to the filepath that YSlow lists as the .js path, I get a 404 error (the .js files are no longer there).

Why would YSlow still see paths to these scripts in the header if they no longer exist? I have deleted cache for WP Super Cache and cleared the browser cache.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In some cases those JS references can be somehow linked in the OPTIONS table, and with bad plugin-writing practice - they can stay there after deactivation.

go to mysite/wp-admin/options.php and look through the options if you see them .

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix would be to use the [clean options plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/clean-options/). Be careful not to delete anything relevant. You might want to back up your Database just in case. Alternatively if you have PHPmyAdmin installed, you can do a search for the rouge script and remove it from the DB Tables.